# Jupyter Notebook save run output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using jupyter notebook to write my code but I'm facing a problem that I have to run all the code each time I run the program.

Is there is a way I can start from where I stopped running to save time? Especially since my code takes around 4 hours to run.

Comment: Not a `deep-learning` question, kindly do not spam irelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) to save all variables at once:

```
import dill
dill.dump_session('notebook.dill')
```

If you want to load it again you can use

```
import dill
dill.load_session('notebook.dill')
```

Unlike pickle, dill can also save modules and methods and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you shut down the Python kernel, the state will be lost inevitably.

A solution could be to persist the relevant data before stopping Jupyter, for example, by using Python's [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pickle.html):

```
import pickle

with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
  pickle.dump(data, f)
```

Later, you can load it as follows:

```
with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
  data = pickle.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

use Pickle model .And try following code

```
   filename = 'model'
   outfile = open(filename,'wb')
   pickle.dump(model_to_save,outfile)
   outfile.close()
```

Comment: make  shore that model name and file name should be valid